# use NFC in android 2.1?

Tags: android, reflection, nfc

I have an android application which I would need to give it support for NFC. I know NFC works in 2.3. Is it anyway to use NFC in previous Android versions through reflection?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to interpret your question. No, you can't use an Android 2.3 feature on a phone that is running Android 2.1. Yes, you can write an app that uses Android 2.3 features but also runs on Android 2.1 phones through reflection.

Comment: so the correct way should be as follows? 
1) Use API version 10 
2) Use some features through reflection using identifying android sdk version 
3) setting min and target versions to be seen in the market 

that is it correct?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Have your app run on Android 2.1 phones, but support Android 2.3 features?

Comment: No problem then. Set the minSdkVersion to 2.1 (8), targetSdkVersion to 2.3 (10), set your API build target to 2.3 (10), and use reflection to get the classes (that, or put them all in a special class that you only ever access if you check the SDK version). NOTE: You may want to set the API build target to 2.1 shortly before you ship just to make sure you didn't accidentally use 2.2+ features, then set it back to 2.3.

Answer (score 1):

Well, i'm just curious. But shouldn't the actual hardware support NFC for this to work?